# Alternative to MSMQ for use in Windows Store Applications

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, msmq, netmsmqbinding, msmq-wcf

I recently discovered that [NetMsmqBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netmsmqbinding.aspx) is not supported in Windows Store Apps,
are there any alternative ways to implement a similar system of queuing messages to a host machine from a tablet?

**Thank you!**

Comment: You should be able to configure [MSMQ over Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164041.aspx), which will allow you to retain your server side queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay after I concluded that there is no way to use **MSMQ** in **Win Store Apps** I found a great article that discusses a way to implement a **OCA(Occasionally Connected Application)** which is perfect for what I want to use-

**EDIT:** Start with [Using SQLite in Windows 8 Store Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx) instead of

[SYNCHRONIZING WINRT/SQLITE USING SYNC FRAMEWORK TOOLKIT](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/synchronizing-winrtsqlite-using-sync-framework-toolkit/)

A simplified component list of the **Microsoft Sync Framework Toolkit**:

- Sync Service (uses Sync Framework 2.1, WCF-based, coupled to SQL
  Server/Express/LocalDB/Azure SQL)
- Cache Controller (client-side,    similar to
  SyncAgent/SyncOrchestrator in Sync Framework)
- Offline Provider (a sync provider)
- Storage Handler (the actual code that    interacts with the database/
  local store/cache)

***Try it out!***